# Sending complex messages to discord bot through R

Tags: r, json, discord

I'm using POST from the httr package to send messages through a discord bot as large scripts update, and I'd like to make these messages a little more complicated than they currently are.

My problem is that the following messages just return the same single word "try".

```
library(httr)

POST(url = "<mywebhook>",
     body = list(content = "try"),
     encode = "json")

POST(url = "<mywebhook>",
     body = list(content = "try",
                 embed = list(title = "this is a title",
                              ThumbnailUrl = "<someimage.png>")),
     encode = "json")
```

My rough understanding is that i can mimic the json format through a series of nested lists for the embed, but that doesn't seem to be true.

Ideally I'd like to set up the embed such that I can send updated plots to a server while something is running, or programmatically generated text strings to provide information about a script's activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typo mistake. Proper element is `embeds` no `embed`, and it is array of objects so in R it should be list of lists:

```
POST(
    url = "<mywebhook>"
    ,body = list(
        content = "try"
        ,embeds = list(
            list(
                title = "this is a title"
                ,ThumbnailUrl = "<someimage.png>"
            )
        )
    )
    ,encode = "json"
)
```